# Console Based Application Doesn't Show Suggestions

Tags: java, console-application, java.util.scanner

I am working on a console based Java application. I've to show suggestions to user for selecting a database. I am using `Scanner` for reading input and a separate thread for checking if input contains `TAB` in order to print the suggestions.

**UPDATE**

As per below answer, I added synchronized block to code and the Exception is gone. However, I don't see any suggestions printed on the console.  Below is my current code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {

    private static List<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        suggestions.add("H2");
        suggestions.add("Mongo");
        suggestions.add("MySQL");
        suggestions.add("Oracle");
        suggestions.add("PostgreSQL");
        suggestions.add("SQLite");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a database name, press TAB for suggestions");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                            String input = scanner.next();
                            if (input.contains("\\t")) {
                                System.out.println(getSuggestions(input));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        synchronized (lock) {
            String selectedDatabase = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(selectedDatabase);
        }

    }

    private static List<String> getSuggestions(String input) {
        List<String> possibleSuggestions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String suggestion : suggestions) {
            if (suggestion.startsWith(input)) {
                possibleSuggestions.add(suggestion);
            }
        }
        return possibleSuggestions;
    }

}
```

Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, `Scanner` is not a thread-safe class and you are using it in two different threads.

You instantiate the scanner it in the Main thread and use it in the other one. In the background the constructor of Scanner might have initialized fields that are not necessarily synced to the other thread.

And while the other thread runs you do a `scanner.nextLine()` in the Main thread which might execute at the exact same time as the other thread doing a `scanner.hasNext()`, leading to concurrent access.

You need a way to synchronize access to the scanner (everywhere), e.g. by means of a *lock*.

```
synchronized (lock) {
    if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String input = scanner.next();
        if (input.contains("\\t")) {
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

where the lock is a static field you synchronize on:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();
```

Comment: So is it not possible to use Scanner for this purpose?

Comment: I tried your answer, but still get the same exception.

Comment: @Beginner You need to synchronize all access to the scanner. Don't forget `scanner.nextLine()` in the Main thread.

Comment: Ok, the Exception is gone now. However, I don't see the suggestions on pressing `TAB` key. What could be the problem?